# Product of independent martingales is adapted

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, expected-value

Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a probability space and suppose $(F_{n})_{n\geq1}$ and $(G_{n})_{n\geq1}$ are independent filtrations. ($F_{n}$ independent of $G_{n}, \forall n\geq1$). Suppose $(M_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is a martingale with respect to $(F_{n})_{n\geq1}$, and  $(L_{n})_{n\geq1}$ a martingale with respect to $(G_{n})_{n\geq1}$. I want to show their product $Z_{n}=M_{n}L_{n}$ is a martingale with respect to $(H_{n})_{n\geq1}$ where $H_{n}=\sigma(F_{n}\cup G_{n})$.

I'm trying to be very clear when showing that this martingale is adapted with respect to $(H_{n})_{n\geq1}$. I understand that $E(|Z_{n}|)=E(|M_{n}L_{n}|)=E(|M_{n}||L_{n}|)$. It makes sense to me that this should give $E(|M_{n}||L_{n}|)=E(|M_{n}|)E(|L_{n}|)$ since the filtrations are independent, but I'm struggling to work out the details of this. The definition of independence I am using is $\forall A\in F_{n}, \forall B\in G_{n}, P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Is this a conjecture or you know the statement is true?

Comment: It was stated in part of a solution for a problem I was set for one of my classes. So I believe it is true unless I have missed something when describing the problem on here.

Answer (score 1):

$M_n L_n \in L^1$ if both $M_n$ and $L_n$ are $L^1$ part:
$$ \mathbb E[|M_nL_n|] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[|M_n||L_n|\ \big|\ F_n]] = \mathbb E[|M_n| \mathbb E[|L_n|\big|\ F_n]] = \mathbb E[|M_n| \mathbb E[|L_n|]] = \mathbb E[|M_n|]\mathbb E[|L_n|] $$
due to the fact that $M_n$ is $F_n$-measurable and $L_n$ is independent of $F_n$.

The martingale part: It is to show that for any $k<n$
$$ \mathbb E[M_nL_n\big| H_k] = M_k L_k. $$

Claim: $H_n$ is generated by the sets $A\cap B$, where $A\in F_n$ and $B\in G_n$.

Proof: Since $\Omega \in F_n,G_n$ we can see that
$$ F_n, G_n \subset \{A\cap B, A\in F_n,B\in G_n\}. $$
Futhermore for $A\in F_n, B \in G_n$ we have that $A,B\in H_n $ and so, since $H_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $A\cap B \in H_n$, hence
$$ H_n  = \sigma (F_n \cup G_n)\subset \sigma(\{A\cap B, A\in F_n, B\in G_n\})\subset H_n \quad\quad \Box. $$

Since $H_n$ is generated by the sets $\{A\cap B, A\in F_n,B\in G_n\}$ it is enough to show that
$$  \mathbb E[\mathbb E[M_nL_n\big| H_k] {\bf 1}(A\cap B)] = \mathbb E[M_k L_k\cdot {\bf 1}(A\cap B)]. $$
for any $A\in F_k, B\in G_k$. It is easy to check that ${\bf 1}(A\cap B) = {\bf 1}(A)\cdot{\bf 1}(B)$, and that $\mathbb E[M_n|H_k]=M_k$ and $\mathbb E[L_n|H_k] = L_k$, hence
$$ \mathbb E[\mathbb E[M_nL_n|H_k]{\bf 1}(A\cap B)] = \mathbb E [M_nL_n {\bf 1}(A) {\bf 1}(B)]= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[M_nL_n{\bf 1}(A){\bf 1}(B)|F_n]] = \mathbb E[M_n{\bf 1}(A)\mathbb E[L_n{\bf 1}(B)|F_n]] = \mathbb E[M_n{\bf 1}(A)]\mathbb E[L_n {\bf 1}(B)] = \mathbb E[M_k {\bf 1}(A)]\mathbb E[L_k{\bf 1}(B)] $$
where the last equality is due to the fact that $M_n$ and $L_n$ are martingales. Now
$$ \mathbb E[M_k{\bf 1}(A)]\mathbb E[L_k{\bf 1}(B)] = \mathbb E[M_kL_k{\bf 1}(A\cap B)] $$
since $M_k$ and $L_k$ are independent, and so are $A\in F_k $ and $B\in G_k$. Thus we showed that 
$$ \mathbb E[M_nL_n | H_k ] = M_kL_k. $$

Comment: Hello. I would like to understand better this solution and I would have two questions. (1) You say that you need and use a set that generates $H_k$. Such a set are by definition all sets A and B. By symmetry than one can prove things just for all A sets. Could you then have than looked just at veryfying that  $E[E[M_nL_n|H_k]1_{A}]=E[M_kL_k1_{A}]$ for every A? (2) Where do you use in the derivation that $E[M_n|H_k]=M_k$ ? and what is the easy proof of this ?

Comment: ( sorry in question one you use a set that generates $H_n$ that was a typo, but I hope my question was clear )

Comment: I used both all the fact, i.e. that both are martingales and that they are independent. It is not enough to show just for ${\bf 1} (A)$, one has to use ${\bf 1}(A\cap B)$. Plus we use the fact that a property is true for a set that generates a sigma-algebra, then it is also true for the whole sigma-algebra.

Comment: Mmm... following what you say, we have that $\sigma(A \cup B)=H_n$ so that $A \cup B$ generate the sigma algebra by definition. Further, since the role of $A$ and $B$ is symmetric in the problem, one can consider only $A$ sets. What is wrong with this reasoning ?

Comment: Okay, given a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, and an $\mathcal F$-measurable RV $Y$ and a general RV $X$, $Y= \mathbb E [X |\mathcal F]$ is equivalent with $\mathbb E[Y {\bf 1}(A)] = \mathbb E [\mathbb E[X|\mathcal F] {\bf 1}(A)]$ for all $A\in \mathcal F$. We are using this to prove the desired equality.

Comment: My (first) question is this. Call $X_n=\{ A \cap B | A \in F_n, B \in G_n\}$ and  $Y_n=F_n \cup G_n$. Than we have $\sigma(X_n)=\sigma(Y_n)=H_n$. You used $Y_n$. Why cannot you use $X_n$, which is smaller and generates $H_n$ ?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. We could have used $Y_n$ too, by checking the equality for any $A$ in $F_n$ and for $G_n$. That wroks too.